# VBA TextBox.Text values are not being written to the spreadsheet correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a UserForm that contains a number of TextBoxes with client information that either accepts info for a new client, or allows an existing client to be edited via a ComboBox selector. Selecting an existing client populates the TextBoxes from cells on a worksheet.  Command buttons allows the user to save, cancel or clear the TextBoxes and ComboBox.

An if statement in the "Save" button code checks whether it is a new or existing client and then executes the following code (Client_Row is declared as a global variable that gets set on Combo_Client_List_Change):

```
Dim lRow_Client As Integer

If Combo_Client_List.Value = "" Then

    lRow_Client = Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(lRow_Client, 1) = lRow_Client - 1
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(lRow_Client, 2) = Name_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(lRow_Client, 3) = Contact_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(lRow_Client, 4) = Telephone_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(lRow_Client, 5) = Site_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(lRow_Client, 6) = SETA_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(lRow_Client, 7) = Comment_Box.Text

Else

    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Client_Row, 2) = Name_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Client_Row, 3) = Contact_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Client_Row, 4) = Telephone_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Client_Row, 5) = Site_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Client_Row, 6) = SETA_Box.Text
    Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Client_Row, 7) = Comment_Box.Text

End If
```

The first part works. If the ComboBox is blank the values are added on the end of my list of clients exactly as intended. 
What blows my brain is that the second part only changes Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Client_Row, 2) in my spreadsheet and reverts to the old values for the rest. 
I've checked that the Client_Row variable is being pulled correctly with MsgBox after each line and that isn't the problem.

It's probably something obvious but my brain is smoking. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Update:

So, I've figured out the following:
If I comment out the first line of the 'Else' statement, everything works as intended. For some reason the code stops executing after copying the Name_Box.Text string to the workbook. 
Still no idea why this happens as the Client_Row variable is not affected and appears to get passed correctly to the remaining lines of code as per the Immediate window:

```
Cells(6, 2) = New Client 5 5 65
Cells(6, 3) = Person
Cells(6, 4) = 12 1111 111
Cells(6, 5) = Not Applicable
Cells(6, 6) = Test
Cells(6, 7) = Testing test test
```

Another strange thing is that if I change the value of Name_Box.Text and hit save but don't select a new client from the ComboBox, it will update all fields if I hit save again. This kind of makes sense because the Client_Row variable is only reset on Combo_Box_Change, but why work now and not in others?

I suspect it has something to do with the RowSource of the ComboBox, but can't see how as nothing changes the Client_Row variable once it is initially set?

Comment: Do you have any `Worksheet_Change` events that is checking the changes in the range of existing data and prevents it?

Comment: Going solely off the code shown, you don't assign a value to `lRow_Client` in the  `Else` portion. I'm surprised it doesn't immediately error  due to row 0 not existing. I'd recommend moving the `lRow_Client` assignment line to before the If statement so that it's defined the same either way.

Comment: I'm also noticing that in the `Else` portion, the row variable is named `Client_Row` instead of `lRow_Client`, is that intentional?  `Client_Row` is never defined either.

Comment: Open the immediate window (menu bar: View -> Immediate window) and put 
`Debug.Print "Cells(" & Cstr(Client_Row) & ", " & "2) = " &  Name_Box.Text`
between each assignment.  Update the column number and text box names as appropriate.  It should print out in the immediate window so you can see if your coordinates and values are what you expect.

Comment: Vitaly - I don't

Comment: @tigeravatar - `lRowClient` isn't needed in the Else section. Client_Row is a public variable that is assigned when the user selects a client name from the ComboBox with: 
`Client_Row = Sheets("Client_DB").Columns(2).Find(What:=Client_Name, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).row`
That bit works. I ran the Debug. Print as suggested by LanchPad and the output confirms that Client_Row is being correctly assigned.

`Cells(6, 2) = New Client 5 5 65
Cells(6, 3) = Person
...`

It just refuses to update the text in my spreadsheet in anything other than (6, 2)

Comment: @LanchPad
I did as you suggested and get the following result:
Cells(6, 2) = New Client 5 5 65
Cells(6, 3) = Person
Cells(6, 4) = 12 1111 111
Cells(6, 5) = Not Applicable
Cells(6, 6) = Test
Cells(6, 7) = Testing test test

This tells me that the correct row is being assigned to Client_Row, but that it still refuses to update the text stored in columns 3 - 7. Column 2 updates though. I'm perplexed

Comment: **[1]** What happens if you move the `Sheets("Client_DB").Cells(Client_Row, 2) = Name_Box.Text` line so it executes after all the ones that aren't updating?
**[2]** Above the `IF` statement, put `On Error Goto 0` to ensure errors are getting thrown (they could provide more info).  
**[3]** Have you implemented any event handlers that may be called while you're updating the workbook. (i.e. Workbook_NewSheet, Workbok_SheetSelectionChange, etc.)

Comment: @LanchPad Moving that line to the bottom seems to solve the issue. You would have thought I would have thought of that, eh? I'm still a bit confused as to WHY it was giving me this drama, but it works fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not a solution I feel good about since the root cause wasn't identified, but I'm glad you were able to get it working the way you wanted!

Comment: @LanchPad I'm just happy that it's working. I'm putting it down to Excel bugs. Had another instance when exporting Excel data to a Word document using bookmarks where Excel refused to pass the last variable on. Solution was to include a dummy variable as the last in the Dim line and then it worked. Don't know why it bugged out, but it did. Anyway. I appreciate your help and input on this issue.